# Cron fails at night

Tags: cron

I have set up a cron job, but for some reason it fails to run during the night. The same job runs fine when i'm running it during the day (i.e. setting up the same job to run in a few minutes and waiting for it to run).

Some logs:

```
Jun 17 14:04:01 server CRON[20174]: (root) CMD (/home/server/scripts/sync.sh >> /home/server/logs/nightly.log 2>&1)
Jun 17 14:12:01 server CRON[20349]: (root) CMD (/home/server/scripts/sync.sh >> /home/server/logs/nightly.log 2>&1)
Jun 17 14:23:01 server CRON[20513]: (root) CMD (/home/server/scripts/sync.sh >> /home/server/logs/nightly.log 2>&1)
Jun 18 01:00:01 server CRON[25717]: (root) CMD (/home/server/scripts/sync.sh >> /home/server/logs/nightly.log 2>&1) # this runs during the night
Jun 18 01:00:01 server CRON[25706]: (CRON) error (grandchild #25717 failed with exit status 2) # doesn't leave anything behind it, not even the nightly.log file - as though the command itself is invalid)
```

cron entry looks like this:

```
0 1 * * * /home/server/scripts/sync.sh >> /home/server/logs/nightly.log 2>&1
```

script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SUCCESS=0
echo "Running nightly automation..."
echo "Running xxxx script..."
SUCCESS=`/home/server/scripts/xxxx.sh && echo 1`
if [ $SUCCESS -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "xxxx success!"
else
        echo "xxxx fail!"
fi
echo "Running rsync..."
/usr/bin/rsync -am --remove-source-files /path1/ /path2/ --log-file=/home/server/logs/sync.log && echo "rsync success!"
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of that file?

Comment: does it even matter? the code doesn't depend on time, and it runs during the day - so there should be no reason for it to fail at night.

Comment: small update - the script now doesn't fail (at least according to cron) but it still leaves no logs or anything else behind, as if it didn't even run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the source of the problem.

Turns out, i had home directory encryption enabled, and my script resided inside that encrypted directory. This is why script never failed when i ran it myself - i was logged in so the path was valid. Hope this might help someone else.

Comment: Thank you for this. Helped me to fix my issue, which was exactly the same. Did you decrypt your drive? or move your script somewhere else (and if so where)?